# AudioRecord read (byte[] audioData, int offsetInBytes, int sizeInBytes) equivalent in iOS

Tags: ios, audio, avaudiorecorder, audiotoolbox

We have a requirement to record audio into a buffer of size 512 bytes continuously in iOS. There is an algorithm processing this buffer.

In android we used AudioRecord's read (byte[] audioData, int offsetInBytes, int sizeInBytes) function. However in iOS there is no equivalent of the same.

We tried a lot with AudioToolBox as well. But its not working fine.

## import "ViewController.h"

```
void AudioInputCallback(void * inUserData,

                    AudioQueueRef inAQ,

                    AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer,

                    const AudioTimeStamp * inStartTime,

                    UInt32 inNumberPacketDescriptions,

                    const AudioStreamPacketDescription * inPacketDescs)

{

RecordState * recordState = (RecordState*)inUserData;

if (!recordState->recording)

{

    printf("Not recording, returning\n");

}



OSStatus status = AudioFileWritePackets(recordState->audioFile,

                                        false,

                                        inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize,

                                        inPacketDescs,

                                        recordState->currentPacket,

                                        &inNumberPacketDescriptions,

                                        inBuffer->mAudioData);

if (status == 0)

{

    recordState->currentPacket += inNumberPacketDescriptions;

}



AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(recordState->queue, inBuffer, 0, NULL);

}








- (void)setupAudioFormat:(AudioStreamBasicDescription*)format

{

format->mSampleRate = 44100;

format->mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;

format->mFramesPerPacket = 1;

format->mChannelsPerFrame = 1;

format->mBytesPerFrame =  format->mBytesPerPacket =format->mChannelsPerFrame * sizeof (SInt16);;



format->mBitsPerChannel = 16;

format->mReserved = 0;

format->mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsBigEndian     |

kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger |

kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;

}





- (void)startRecording

{

[self setupAudioFormat:&recordState.dataFormat];



recordState.currentPacket = 0;



OSStatus status;

status = AudioQueueNewInput(&recordState.dataFormat,

                            AudioInputCallback,

                            &recordState,

                            CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),

                            kCFRunLoopCommonModes,

                            0,

                            &recordState.queue);



if (status == 0)

{

    // Prime recording buffers with empty data

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BUFFERS; i++)

    {

        AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(recordState.queue, 16000, &recordState.buffers[i]);

        AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer (recordState.queue, recordState.buffers[i], 0, NULL);

    }

    

    status = AudioFileCreateWithURL(fileURL,

                                    kAudioFileAIFFType,

                                    &recordState.dataFormat,

                                    kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,

                                    &recordState.audioFile);

    if (status == 0)

    {

        recordState.recording = true;

        status = AudioQueueStart(recordState.queue, NULL);

        if (status == 0)

        {

            labelStatus.text = @"Recording";

        }

    }

}



- (void)startRecording

{

[self setupAudioFormat:&recordState.dataFormat];



recordState.currentPacket = 0;



OSStatus status;

status = AudioQueueNewInput(&recordState.dataFormat,

                            AudioInputCallback,

                            &recordState,

                            CFRunLoopGetCurrent(),

                            kCFRunLoopCommonModes,

                            0,

                            &recordState.queue);



if (status == 0)

{

    // Prime recording buffers with empty data

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BUFFERS; i++)

    {

        AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(recordState.queue, 16000, &recordState.buffers[i]);

        AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer (recordState.queue, recordState.buffers[i], 0, NULL);

    }

    

    status = AudioFileCreateWithURL(fileURL,

                                    kAudioFileAIFFType,

                                    &recordState.dataFormat,

                                    kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,

                                    &recordState.audioFile);

    if (status == 0)

    {

        recordState.recording = true;

        status = AudioQueueStart(recordState.queue, NULL);

        if (status == 0)

        {

                      }

    }

}



if (status != 0)

{

    [self stopRecording];

 

    }

}


}
```

Comment: what do you mean it's not working fine?

Comment: @madhu have you got the counterpart of AudioRecord's read function for iOS ??